# Sharepoint rest GetFileByServerRelativeUrl returns wrong results

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, pnp-js-core

So I have a document library at https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Test/Documents/

and I have a document in it called Doc1.docx. It has an Item Id of 1.

I use the following rest call in a browser to get the id of the list item associated with the document

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Test/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Test/Documents/Doc1.docx')/listItemAllFields?$select=Id,Title
```

As expected it comes back with the proper list item id of one.

Now I go and delete Doc1.docx from the library, and then upload it again. Now the Doc1.docx has  the item Id of 2, right?

I use the same rest call to get the Id of the list item associated with the document

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Test/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Test/Documents/Doc1.docx')/listItemAllFields?$select=Id,Title
```

It still says the list Item ID is still one.

As a workaround I ended up including the 'Modified' field in the $select parameter. This makes it return the proper results.

Update : this  workaraound stopped working. Now I got it working by leaving off the # select.

Also note that I am generating these rest calls with-pnp-js-core. Not that that should male any difference:

```
return pnp.sp.web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(results.data.ServerRelativeUrl).getItem<{ Id: number, Title: string, Modified: Date }>("Id", "Title", "Modified").then((item) => {
```

Is this the expected behaviour of getFileByServerRelativeUrl or is this a bug?

Comment: Maybe the ajax call was cached...?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I checked it in fiddler, let me double check that.

Comment: yep, fiddler shows sharepoint online is returning HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified, when, in fact, I deleted and upload a new version of the file. Worse yet, my  workaround stopped 'working around  the issue.

Answer (score 3):

For similar ajax calls to SP REST API try use noncache factor on your request url. Example:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Test/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Test/Documents/Doc1.docx')/listItemAllFields?$select=Id,Title + "?" + new Date().getTime()
```